# Firebase Hosting - Technical Specifications

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been using FirebaseHosting for a while now and enjoying its simplicity and ease. I have also been working with Google Compute & Kubernetes Engine for hosting client websites. When using Compute & Kubernetes you have to manipulate and work with services such as Load-Balancing, CDN, Autoscaling, Machine Types etc.

Firebase Hosting does not give any information regarding technical specifications of the hosting service other than saying it uses Google's CDN for faster edge access.

Does anyone have any information regarding Firebase Hosting's technical specs particularly Compute, so as to know if it will suite scaling and other client requirements?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Since Firebase Hosting is only for static resources (HTML, CSS, client-side JavaScript, etc), there is no "compute" in Firebase Hosting.

Comment: I see, so Firebase hosting wouldn't be a great candidate for an application that does some moderate to heavy Javascript computations? I just wanted to know if the underlying servers hosting my webpage could handle the computations as fast as possible

Comment: Firebase Hosting will not be running your computations. You can integrate it with Cloud Functions, which *can* run your code on Google's servers. Its quotas are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Hosting will not be running your computations. Since Firebase Hosting is only for static resources (HTML, CSS, client-side JavaScript, etc), there is no "compute" in Firebase Hosting.

You can integrate it with Cloud Functions, which can run your code on Google's servers. Its quotas are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits

Comment: FYI: [Firebase Hosting Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) says `Firebase Hosting provides fast and secure hosting for your web app, static and dynamic content, and microservices.` Granted, the documentation is wrong, just sayin...

Comment: That's why I point out the integration between Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions to serve dynamic content.

Comment: Just an FYI to update the answer: Dynamic content can also be served via integration with [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/)